Is this the correct way to make a bandpass filter?
I'm trying to make a bandpass filter for a low voltage noisy electrical signal coming from a K-Type thermocouple
To identify the frequencies I would need to filter out, I make a spectrum diagram using Matlab.  Here is the Matlab code:
    clear,clearvars, close,clc
    
    %Importing Scope Data
    Scope_Data = load("Data from scope 2.txt");
    
    %Dividing Scope data to Vector of Voltage Data Point and Time data points
    Time_Data = Scope_Data(:,1);
    Volatge_Data = Scope_Data(:,2) * 10^3;
    
    %Applying Fast Fourier Transform to Voltage Data 
    FFT_Signal = fft(Volatge_Data);
    
    % Nonshifted FFT Data 
    Real_Data = real(FFT_Signal);
    Img_Data = imag(FFT_Signal);
    
    %Shifting data which i applied FFT to 
    FFT_Signal_Shift = fftshift(FFT_Signal);
    
    % Shifted FFT Data 
    Real_Data_shifted = real(FFT_Signal_Shift);
    img_Data_shifted = imag(FFT_Signal_Shift);
    
    %  Plotting Real Component Shifted Data 
    subplot(2,1,1)
    plot(Real_Data_shifted)
    xlabel("Frequency Index")
    ylabel("Real Part of FFT of Signal")
    title("Real_fft")
    
    % Plotting imaginary Component Shifted Data 
    subplot(2,1,2)
    plot(img_Data_shifted)
    xlabel("Frequency Index")
    ylabel("Img Part of FFT of Signal")
    title("Img_fft")

Here are the produced spectrum analysis graphs:

Based on this I designed my band bass filter on LTspice to have a bandwidth of 4088-4106 Hz.
Here is the design:

What concerned me is that the out didn't look like it was a filtered signal so I wanted to ask at what stage of this process did I mess up?
Output picture

Is this an acceptable output in the sense of is the signal being filtered properly or not?
It kind of looks sinusoidal and less spikey but I'm not sure if this is actually the expected output of the filtering process.

Are you sure you want a bandpass filter and not a lowpass filter? What are you trying to measure?

Just what kind of signal spectrum are you expecting from a thermocouple..?! This sounds like a highly unusual application; providing additional details/background would be greatly helpful.

I don't see a definition for V1. Did you set this, or is the definition hidden? Why the low values of resistance? That will load down your circuit unless that's what you want.

Instead of plotting the real and imaginary part, you should plot the magnitude. That way the FFT will have a simple physical interpretation. The vertical axis will be in Volt-seconds (or Kelvin-seconds if the temperature is calibrated).

@Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica shouldnt the real component be equivalent to the magnitude ? I am not very good with complex numbers so apologizes if this is wrong

@TimWilliams Im not very sure what to expect to be honest, This is a project college project and the Dr kind of just threw us into the sea and told us figure out to swim. Which is find and pretty fun but it means im pretty blind at to what to expect. It did cross my mind that the output of the thermocouple would be a DC value and a spectrum analysis was overkill but i wasnt sure. I am very new to all these concepts so  my questions being weird and unusual is to be expected lol

@qrk The definition of the voltage comes from a text file which contains the data from the thermocouple measured via a analogue discover 2 (https://digilent.com/reference/test-and-measurement/analog-discovery-2/start) Its a bunch of discrete data point

@OfficialPyramid Can you post the PWL file. A 4 kHz bandpass filter seems wrong for a thermocouple application. Perhaps a low-pass filter would be a better choice since you want information around DC. Note that the filter takes out the DC signal which is the temperature information.

@qrk im not sure how to upload that file. However i think ive got to the root of my issue. Your right, it makes sense for the Thermocouple to output a DC voltage and so my bandpass filter has basically removed the entire useful part of my signal and is just letting some noise through. I Thought needed a 4 kHz band pass filter because of the fftshift() function i used made it seem like the signal containing the  the information about the temperature was at the 4 Khz region. I will implement a low pass filter as you said since the DC value is at the 0 frequency.

First off, the question is lacking important details which was later supplied in the comments. In the future, it is best to give details.
For a thermocouple, you probably want a low-pass filter. Around DC is the temperature information.
The waveform file you were given, as described in the comments, is the measured signal which includes a component around DC and noise that I assume you want to make smaller.
The Amplitude-vs-Time plot in the LTspice simulation shows a periodic high-frequency signal which is around 50 kHz. I'm not sure why your FFT plot shows a signal around 4 kHz, about a factor of 10 off from the time series shown in LTspice. LTspice has a FFT feature (make the graph active, View->FFT) which you can use to check the FFT results from Matlab. You may want to recheck the FFT computation in Matlab.From this information you can create a low-pass filter to reduce the 50 kHz signal as well as other random noise. Since we don't know the thermal response of the measurement sensor, you will need to find this out so you can choose a reasonable cutoff frequency for the filter.
The FFT plots shows the \$I\$ (in-phase, or real term) & \$Q\$ (quadrature, or imaginary term). For this exercise, it makes sense to plot the magnitude of the FFT signal, not the individual I & Q terms, i.e., \$ |M| = \sqrt{I^2 + Q^2} \$. The maths program you are using probably has a function to convert to magnitude. Although, in this case, the magnitude will be very close to the \$I\$ term since the \$Q\$ term is so small relative to the \$I\$ term. It is also beneficial to plot the magnitude term in a log scale (dB) so you can see the lower amplitude details of the signal.
You should choose better values for the filter. 5 ohm resistors (way too small value) will load the circuitry unnecessarily.

Thank you very much

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
When we use and apply KCL, we can write the following set of equations:
$$\text{I}_1=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_3\tag1$$
When we use and apply Ohm's law, we can write the following set of equations:
$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_1&=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2&=\frac{\text{V}_1-0}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3&=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_3&=\frac{\text{V}_2-0}{\text{R}_4}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$
Substitute \$(2)\$ into \$(1)\$, in order to get:
$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}&=\frac{\text{V}_1-0}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}&=\frac{\text{V}_1-0}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_2-0}{\text{R}_4}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$
Solving for the transfer function gives:
$$\mathscr{H}:=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{V}_\text{i}}=\frac{\text{R}_2\text{R}_4}{\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)+\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)}\tag4$$
We can can set \$\text{s}=\text{j}\omega\$, \$\displaystyle\text{R}_1=\frac{1}{\text{sC}_1}\$ and \$\displaystyle\text{R}_4=\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}\$.
So, the complex transfer function becomes:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_2\cdot\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2}}{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_1}\cdot\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2}\right)+\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_3+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2}\right)}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_2\cdot\frac{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2}}{\displaystyle\frac{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_1}\cdot\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2}\right)+\text{R}_2\left(\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_3+\frac{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2}\right)}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}{\displaystyle\frac{\text{C}_2}{\text{C}_1}\cdot\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2}\right)+\text{R}_2\left(\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_3+1\right)}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_2\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2}{\displaystyle\frac{\text{C}_2}{\text{C}_1}\cdot\left(\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)+\frac{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2}\right)+\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\left(\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_3+1\right)}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_2\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2\text{C}_1}{\displaystyle\frac{\text{C}_2\text{C}_1}{\text{C}_1}\cdot\left(\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)+1\right)+\text{C}_1\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_3+\text{C}_1\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_2}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_2\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2\text{C}_1}{\displaystyle\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2\text{C}_2\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)+\text{C}_2+\text{C}_1\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_3+\text{C}_1\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_2}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\omega\text{j}}{\displaystyle\text{C}_2^2\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)\omega\text{j}+\text{C}_2-\text{C}_1\text{C}_2^2\text{R}_2\text{R}_3\omega^2+\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\omega\text{j}}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\omega\text{j}}{\displaystyle\text{C}_2\left(1-\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{R}_3\omega^2\right)+\text{C}_2\left(\text{C}_1\text{R}_2+\text{C}_2\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)\right)\omega\text{j}}
\end{split}\tag5
\end{equation}
Now, we want to solve for the value that \$\displaystyle\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|\$ is at a maximum:
$$\frac{\partial\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\hat{\omega}\right)\right|}{\partial\hat{\omega}}=0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\hat{\omega}=\dots\tag6$$
Solving this gives:
$$\hat{\omega}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{R}_3}}\tag7$$
At the maximum, we get:
$$\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\hat{\omega}\right)\right|=\frac{\text{C}_1\text{R}_2}{\text{C}_1\text{R}_2+\text{C}_2\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)}\tag8$$
So, the cut-off frequency can be solved:
$$\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\hat{\omega}\right)\right|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{\text{C}_1\text{R}_2}{\text{C}_1\text{R}_2+\text{C}_2\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\omega=\dots\tag9$$
Which gives:
$$\omega_\pm=\frac{2}{\sqrt{4\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{R}_3+\left(\text{C}_1\text{R}_2+\text{C}_2\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)\right)^2}\pm\left(\text{C}_1\text{R}_2+\text{C}_2\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)\right)}\tag{10}$$
So, the bandwidth is given by:
$$\mathcal{B}:=\left|\omega_+-\omega_-\right|=\frac{\text{C}_1\text{R}_2+\text{C}_2\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)}{\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{R}_3}\tag{11}$$
And the quality factor is given by:
$$\mathcal{Q}:=\frac{\hat{\omega}}{\mathcal{B}}=\frac{\sqrt{\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{R}_3}}{\text{C}_1\text{R}_2+\text{C}_2\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)}\tag{12}$$
We can see that the absolute value of your transfer function is given by:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|&=\left|\frac{\displaystyle\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\omega\text{j}}{\displaystyle\text{C}_2\left(1-\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{R}_3\omega^2\right)+\text{C}_2\left(\text{C}_1\text{R}_2+\text{C}_2\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)\right)\omega\text{j}}\right|\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\left|\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\omega\text{j}\right|}{\displaystyle\left|\text{C}_2\left(1-\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{R}_3\omega^2\right)+\text{C}_2\left(\text{C}_1\text{R}_2+\text{C}_2\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)\right)\omega\text{j}\right|}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\omega}{\displaystyle\sqrt{\left(\text{C}_2\left(1-\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{R}_3\omega^2\right)\right)^2+\left(\text{C}_2\left(\text{C}_1\text{R}_2+\text{C}_2\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)\right)\omega\right)^2}}
\end{split}\tag{13}
\end{equation}
And the argument is given by:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\arg\left(\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right)&=\frac{\pi}{2}-\begin{cases}
0&\space\text{if}\space\alpha=0\space\wedge\space\beta=0\\
\\
\frac{\pi}{2}&\space\text{if}\space\alpha=0\space\wedge\space\beta>0\\
\\
\arctan\left(\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right)&\space\text{if}\space\alpha>0\space\wedge\space\beta>0\\
\\
\frac{\pi}{2}+\arctan\left(\frac{\left|\alpha\right|}{\beta}\right)&\space\text{if}\space\alpha<0\space\wedge\space\beta>0
\end{cases}\\
\\
&=\begin{cases}
\frac{\pi}{2}-0&\space\text{if}\space\alpha=0\space\wedge\space\beta=0\\
\\
\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}&\space\text{if}\space\alpha=0\space\wedge\space\beta>0\\
\\
\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right)&\space\text{if}\space\alpha>0\space\wedge\space\beta>0\\
\\
\frac{\pi}{2}-\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\arctan\left(\frac{\left|\alpha\right|}{\beta}\right)\right)&\space\text{if}\space\alpha<0\space\wedge\space\beta>0
\end{cases}\\
\\
&=\begin{cases}
\frac{\pi}{2}&\space\text{if}\space\alpha=0\space\wedge\space\beta=0\\
\\
0&\space\text{if}\space\alpha=0\space\wedge\space\beta>0\\
\\
\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right)&\space\text{if}\space\alpha>0\space\wedge\space\beta>0\\
\\
-\arctan\left(\frac{\left|\alpha\right|}{\beta}\right)&\space\text{if}\space\alpha<0\space\wedge\space\beta>0
\end{cases}\\
\\
&=\begin{cases}
0&\space\text{if}\space\omega=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{R}_3}}\\
\\
\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right)&\space\text{if}\space0<\omega<\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{R}_3}}\\
\\
-\arctan\left(\frac{\left|\alpha\right|}{\beta}\right)&\space\text{if}\space\omega>\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{R}_3}}
\end{cases}\\
\\
&=\begin{cases}
0&\space\text{if}\space\omega=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{R}_3}}\\
\\
\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(\frac{\left(\text{C}_1\text{R}_2+\text{C}_2\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)\right)\omega}{1-\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{R}_3\omega^2}\right)&\space\text{if}\space0<\omega<\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{R}_3}}\\
\\
-\arctan\left(\frac{\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{R}_3\omega^2-1}{\left(\text{C}_1\text{R}_2+\text{C}_2\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)\right)\omega}\right)&\space\text{if}\space\omega>\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{R}_3}}
\end{cases}
\end{split}\tag{14}
\end{equation}
Where \$\alpha:=1-\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{R}_3\omega^2\$ and \$\beta:=\left(\text{C}_1\text{R}_2+\text{C}_2\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)\right)\omega\$.

posting long answers copied from mathematicas solver is not the best way to answer a question. Also solving homework for people goes against the site and it's community.
